# How to work with drop down menu and input text boxes in selenium and python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, drop-down-menu, textbox

I'm working with selenium in python and in [this web page](https://www.mql5.com/en/trading) I want to choose between different options in a drop down menu and then enter some values.
In that webpage, after I click on the "new order" button, a new windows pops up and I have to choose between symbols, for example, "USDCAD". After that I have to enter some values such as "take profit" and "stop loss". I don't know how to do these because unfortunately I don't know much about how web pages work and what HTML is and...!
This is the code that I wrote for selecting between drop down menu options but I get error:

```
def fast_multiselect(driver, element_id, labels):
    select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id(element_id))
    for label in labels:
        select.select_by_visible_text(label)
fast_multiselect(driver, 'symbol', "USDCAD")
```

And this is the error that I get:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.UnexpectedTagNameException: Message: Select only works on <select> elements, not on <th>
```

Complete code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')
driver.get('https://www.mql5.com/en/trading')
time.sleep(10)
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='webTerminalHost']")))
time.sleep(10)
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@title='New Order']/span"))).click()
time.sleep(5)
def fast_multiselect(driver, element_id, labels):
    select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id(element_id))
    for label in labels:
        select.select_by_visible_text(label)
fast_multiselect(driver, 'symbol', "USDCAD")
```

I will be so thankful if you help me choose from the drop down menu and enter those values. And also if you explain some important and basic things or if a quick guide (maybe a useful link) which helps me understand how I should deal with HTML codes for basic jobs like my question.

Comment: It seems you got the wrong select tag identicator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to target a select tag.

```
<select class="input-combobox" id="order-dialog-symbol">
<option value="USDCAD">USDCAD, US Dollar vs Canadian Dollar</option>
```

The bottom would work

```
fast_multiselect(driver, 'order-dialog-symbol', ["USDCAD"])
```

If you replaced

```
select.select_by_visible_text(label)
```

with

```
select.select_by_value(label)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. it gives me this error: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Cannot locate option with value: U

Comment: Check the fix now.fast_multiselect(driver, 'order-dialog-symbol', ["USDCAD"]) Handles multiple values now.

Comment: Where can I found this source code? : <select class="input-combobox" id="order-dialog-symbol">

Comment: But it gives me:
<select class="input-combobox" id="symbol" style="position: absolute; left: 410px; width: 323px; top: 22px;">
And the id="symbol", but the id you wrote is "order-dialog-symbol"

Comment: Ok go to the developer tools-> ctrl-f -> <select> . When you go through them one will highlight over the page as the one you want. id='symbol'  isn't valid for anything but a th which isn't clickable.